# How to show username in reply to comment?

Tags: comments

How to show username in reply to comment ?
Please provide an example code on how to implement this.
It needs to be done as shown in the picture:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $comment = get_comment( $current_comment_id )->comment_author; something like that, but I can't do anything, too little experience, I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

the formatting you want to change typically lives in a comments.php file in the root directory of the theme, though different themes can deal with comments in different ways. There are even themes (Divi themes do this, for example) that let you turn elements like author on and off as part of customizing the theme.

If you're making the changes yourself, though, you'll need to find the part of the template where the header for the comment is written and add a call to get_comment_author();

Comment: (And unless you're using a custom-built theme, you should set up a child theme to make the changes. Otherwise, your changes will be overwritten every time there's a theme update.)

Comment: i create my theme from scratch

Comment: Are there any free themes with this functionality?

Comment: write the names of any topics that have support for this, even paid ones